# How to make sure background fills the whole flex row which overflows?

Tags: css, flexbox

How to make sure that background-color fills the whole flex row which overflows to the right? Currently, it only fills a portion of it that fits on the screen.

Here's an example:

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.wrapper:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.content {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question to better match my real use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to disable the stretch alignment by setting `align-items:start` the consider `min-width:100%` on the wrapper:

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:start; /* added */
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.wrapper {
  min-width:100%; /* added */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.wrapper:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.content {
  min-width: 150px;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.wrapper` content is overflowing, but it does not overflow
You could remove the `overflow-x:scroll` from `main`, and use `overflow-x:auto` in the `.wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a width to any `.content`(e.g: **width:30%**) then set `width: 180%` to `.wrapper`. since you have **6** div tag in the any wrapper:

```css
main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  }

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 180%;
  border: 1px solid red;

}
.wrapper:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.content {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

Move `background-color` from `.wrapper` to `main`.

Your `main` element is what is being scrolled.